# XMLNSC attributes

Tags: xml, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am getting the below message from an application

```
        field:CHARACTER:abcd
                mv:CHARACTER:1
                name:CHARACTER:NAME
                sv:CHARACTER:1
        field:CHARACTER:aaaaa
                mv:CHARACTER:1
                name:CHARACTER:Address
                sv:CHARACTER:1
        field:CHARACTER:123456
                mv:CHARACTER:1
                name:CHARACTER:Phone
                sv:CHARACTER:1
```

and i am parsing the above into XML and the code is:

```
SET OutputRoot.XML.EE_EAI_MESSAGE.Response.NAME     =   InputRoot.XMLNSC.Ns1:TNS.Ns1:Response.Ns1:Processed.Ns1:field[1];
SET OutputRoot.XML.EE_EAI_MESSAGE.Response.ADDRESS  =   InputRoot.XMLNSC.Ns1:TNS.Ns1:Response.Ns1:Processed.Ns1:field[2];
SET OutputRoot.XML.EE_EAI_MESSAGE.Response.MOBILE   =   InputRoot.XMLNSC.Ns1:TNS.Ns1:Response.Ns1:Processed.Ns1:field[3];
```

I have a problem as the application never includes an empty field in response message so the application is sending the message as

```
        field:CHARACTER:abcd
                mv:CHARACTER:1
                name:CHARACTER:NAME
                sv:CHARACTER:1
        field:CHARACTER:123456
                mv:CHARACTER:1
                name:CHARACTER:Phone
                sv:CHARACTER:1
```

the `Address` field is missing in the above input message. According to my `esql` code the data is incorrectly mapped due to field index. So i need to map the fields by checking the tagnames in input message, but i am not able to do... I am very thankful if anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
SET OutputRoot.XML.EE_EAI_MESSAGE.Response.NAME     =  THE (SELECT T FROM  InputRoot.XMLNSC.Ns1:TNS.Ns1:Response.Ns1:Processed.Ns1:field[] AS T WHERE T.name='NAME');
SET OutputRoot.XML.EE_EAI_MESSAGE.Response.ADDRESS  =  THE (SELECT T FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.Ns1:TNS.Ns1:Response.Ns1:Processed.Ns1:field[] AS T WHERE T.name='Address');
SET OutputRoot.XML.EE_EAI_MESSAGE.Response.MOBILE   =  THE (SELECT T FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.Ns1:TNS.Ns1:Response.Ns1:Processed.Ns1:field[] AS T WHERE T.name='Phone');